# Algorithm - How to show Big O for 2 functions

Tags: asymptotics

I believe that Ln(n) is <= 2^(sqrt(2*lg(n))), so I am trying to prove it

I know that you can show Big O by showing Little O, so I am trying to take the limit as n approaches infinity of Ln(n)/2^(sqrt(2*lg(n)))

However I am finding it hard to prove this using the limit definition

I would appreciate any help to see how to solve this! Thanks

Comment: Please make your formulas uniquely parseable. What is `lgn`? Is `2lgn` the same as `2*log(n)`?

Comment: Sorry about that, it should be slightly better to read. Yeah, 2lgn is the same as 2*log(n)

Comment: @Kneelac Right now you have `2 ^ (2*lg(n)) ^ (1/2)`. Is that the same as `sqrt(2 ^ (2*lg(n)))`?  Or `2^(sqrt(2*lg(n)))`?

Comment: 2 ^ (2*lg(n)) ^ (1/2) is the same as 2^(sqrt(2*lg(n))) Mooing Duck

Comment: @Kneelac: Did you mean `ln` on the left and `lg` on the right?

Comment: @MooingDuck Nope, should be ln on the left and lg on the right

Comment: @Kneelac: You realize those are only a constant-factor from the other, which is ignored in big-O, right?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. The title says "big O", then you change your mind and it's an inequality, then it's suddenly big O again. Could you clarify what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting `lg(n)` as `log2(n)`, set `n=2^x` so that the inequality transforms to

```
ln(2)*x <= 2^sqrt(2*x)
```

Now apply the square root,

```
sqrt(2*ln(2)) * sqrt(x/2) <= 2^sqrt(x/2)
```

and we are left to prove that for `y>0`

```
2^y/y > sqrt(2*ln(2))
```

Indeed, the minimum of the left side can be found for `0=ln(2)*y-1` or `y=1/ln(2)` with minimum value `2^(1/ln(2))*ln(2)`. Numerically, the gap between `1.88416938536372` and `1.1774100225154747` is large enough to exclude any floating point errors. Thus all the equivalent inequalities including the original one are true.